# Method that behaves differently by some arguments type

Tags: c#, methods, types, arguments, behavior

I'm looking for the best way to implement a method that behave differenty according to a type argument (I can't use dynamic here).

> ```cs
> public class Methods
> {
>     public int someMethod1() { return 1; }
>     public string someMethod2() { return "2"; }
>
>     public ??? process(System.Type arg1) ???
>     {
>         if (arg1 is of type int) ??
>             return someMethod1();
>         else if (arg1 is of type string) ??
>             return someMethod2();
>     }
> }
> ```

If my example is not clear, here is my real need :
- The user of my lib can specify what return type he wants from his request,
- Depending on the type asked, i have to use a different set of methods (like `GetValueAsInt32()` or `GetValueAsString()`)

Many thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For interested buddies, I've searched around a lot and I've come up with a solution using generics and reflection:

- The converting generic method:

```cs
public static class MyConvertingClass
{
    public static T Convert<T>(APIElement element)
    {
        System.Type type = typeof(T);
        if (conversions.ContainsKey(type))
            return (T)conversions[type](element);
        else
            throw new FormatException();
    }

    private static readonly Dictionary<System.Type, Func<Element, object>> conversions = new Dictionary<Type,Func<Element,object>>
    {
        { typeof(bool), n => n.GetValueAsBool() },
        { typeof(char), n => n.GetValueAsChar() },
        { typeof(DateTime), n => n.GetValueAsDatetime() },
        { typeof(float), n => n.GetValueAsFloat32() },
        { typeof(double), n => n.GetValueAsFloat64() },
        { typeof(int), n => n.GetValueAsInt32() },
        { typeof(long), n => n.GetValueAsInt64() },
        { typeof(string), n => n.GetValueAsString() }
    };
}
```

- The main method:

```cs
public static main()
{
    // Defined by the user:
    Type fieldType = typeof(double);

    // Using reflection:
    MethodInfo method = typeof(MyConvertingClass).GetMethod("Convert");
    method = method.MakeGenericMethod(fieldType);

    Console.WriteLine(method.Invoke(null, new object[] { fieldData }));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you just use Generic to allow consumers to determine the return type:

```
public T process<T>(Type arg1) {...}
```

Comment: That can't work as in the method body i can't return a type arg1 to T

Comment: I can resolve my problem with a set of if/else if statement but if I do so, I won't generalize this solution to the whole lib and so will get a lot of duplicate sequences (which I don't want).

Comment: you are right. In case of support generics here you will need to add a restriction that T is class in order to case result to T. another variant is to return object and make few public methods which will support returning base types like int, string, decimal, etc.